# Set a background in iOS view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm not an iOS developer. I just need to set a background image for the following controller: 
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/blob/master/ios/RCCViewController.m

I already added the image in images.xcassets folder. What is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are already setting up the background image correctly in code line #99-104. The only reason I can think of is that you haven't specified the frame size for your UIView in which you are setting up the image background. Try setting the frame size equal to frame size of your view and it should work in my opinion.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: yes , but how to center the image horizontally ? currently its starts at top left corner